# Patch apply at wrong location

Tags: bash, diff, patch

I'm attempting to create a set of patch files that i can quickly apply on demand to add or remove alias to `.bashrc`.

To arcive this i added a section for alias in `.bashrc` after the line `# alias` and created a patch file as follows:

```
--- a/.bashrc
+++ b/.bashrc
@@ -50,1 +50,2 @@
 # alias
+alias update-me='sudo pacman -Syu'
```

Becouse i can't tell in advance what set of patches will be used i relay the prefix to locate the right location at `.bashrc`.
While in reality, after attempting to patch `.bashrc` using
`patch .bashrc < patchfile.patch`
im getting:
`Hunk #1 succeeded at 15 with fuzz 1 (offset -35 lines).`
And the new alias is added at the wrong location, at the end of the file rather than after `# alias` while i was expecting it to be added at right after `# alias`.

What am i doing wrong?
Also, is there a better method for managing those kind of changes?

Comment: similar issue like here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414542/30851

Comment: thnkx for the find @frostschutz. It helped create a workaround.
I just added
```
-# alias
+#alias
```
insted of ` # alias`
and it performed the patch currectly

Comment: Read `man run_parts`, remembering to `source` the target files. You could `mkdir $HOME/.bash_alias.d/`, put groups of aliases in individual files.